# Where to find email form in Meteor framework?

Tags: meteor

I have just downloaded Meteor framework from github and running it locally it shows signin/signup page..

Where can I reach that page or the page that contains the email form to authenticate?

I have looked everywhere but with no luck...

Comment: Please share some code, and what exactly are you asking.  There are no sign in/sign up page in meteor.You have to install packages.

Comment: It is part of a different package: accounts-ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the examples have the `accounts-ui` package built in. You can see the documentation here: https://docs.meteor.com/packages/accounts-ui.html

If you are trying to change the style of the login, you'll want to use the `accounts-ui-unstyled` package.

Detailed styling guidlines can be found at: https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#useraccounts